# Suppose that $n$ is a factor of $(n-1)!+1$. Prove that $n$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is in an Algebra and Combinatorics module and I don't know how to prove this. The full question is,

Let $n$ be a natural number greater than $1$. Suppose that $n$ is a factor of $(n-1)!+1$. Prove that $n$ is prime.

Any help would be greatly appreciated -thanks.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the question linked. Indeed, the other question asks for a proof of one implication in Wilson's theorem ("if $p$ is prime then..."), while this question is about the other implication ("if ... then $p$ is prime").

Comment: There is a better target, which is a canonical reference for both directions.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $n=ab$ with $1<a<n$. Then $a\mid (n-1)!$ and $a\nmid (n-1)!+1$, hence $n\nmid (n-1)!+1$.